# Unable to merge TIFFs in one file using Warp and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal-merge

I have three TIFFs are below which is belongs to Alaska HI Chart:

First https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KllacOdKNw866doqjMcounsvofpXBgFh/view?usp=sharing

Second https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Oi8QwIONZ-CXzYRS0Ic-VQPTFAN4u42/view?usp=sharing

third https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BB_DCW59ecSvFESajWoXm5W6Xt0DRbmo/view?usp=sharing

Command:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0.0 -r lanczos -of GTiff -dstalpha -overwrite --optfile test.txt "C:/Users/Nivesh.shastri/Documents/test3alaskahi/delete/merge.tif"
```

`test.txt` contains path of TIFF files. After completion of command, generated `merge.tif` is blank and same with `QGIS`.

Also getting warning like: `band 5: Band 4 was already identified as alpha band, and band 5 is now marked as alpha too`

My primary goal is to merge all TIFF into one TIFF then Translate it to MBTiles using `-projwin` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gdalwarp `-dstalpha`is used for adding an alpha band https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-dstalpha

> **-dstalpha**
>
> Create an output alpha band to identify nodata (unset/transparent)
> pixels.

Because your source images already have an alpha band there is no need for -dstalpha. This command runs without errors.

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0.0 -r lanczos -of GTiff test1_translate.tif test2_translate.tif test3_translate.tif merge.tif
Creating output file that is 78105P x 29032L.
Using band 4 of destination image as alpha.
Processing test1_translate.tif [1/3] : 0Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. 0) for image test1_translate.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Processing test2_translate.tif [2/3] : 0Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. 0) for image test2_translate.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Processing test3_translate.tif [3/3] : 0Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. 0) for image test3_translate.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Comment: First of all ty for your answer, as per your suggestion I have removed <-dstalpha>, TIFFs has been merge successfully. But while translating <gdal_translate -of MBTiles -projwin -207.4014861258131361 74.1710011162752068 -119.4373264976983933 41.4743045882241574 C:\Users\admin\Downloads\gdal\merge.tif C:\Users\admin\Downloads\gdal\transalte.mbtiles> it stuck at 0% and its been 4 hours but didn't completed yet any suggestions?

https://imgur.com/a/fzF3eTS

Comment: It took 20 minutes for me `gdal_translate -of MBTiles -projwin -207.4014861258131361 74.1710011162752068 -119.4373264976983933 41.47430458822 merge.tif merge.mbtiles
Input file size is 78105, 29032
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.` GDAL 3.5.0 on Windows with the binaries from gisinternals.com.

Comment: I am getting warning like Invalid value for 'bounds' metadata. Ignoring it and fall back to present tile extent while execute command 'gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW -r nearest translate.mbtiles' for generated mbtiles using translate.

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: It is just a warning and GDAL tries to use a reasonable fall back . Do you have problems with the result?

Comment: yes MBTiles not showing on map, I am using https://mousebird-consulting-inc.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/ in IPad.   Let me try once again whole process

Comment: Test also with QGIS to see it your client has some special requirements.

Comment: please tell me how to test in QGIS, Just drag n drop?

Comment: Should work like that or through Layer - Add raster layer.

Comment: I think it is not valid, generated MBTiles https://imgur.com/a/9wDykXb and merge image looks like this https://imgur.com/a/z1y2d6I

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138361/discussion-between-nivesh-shastri-and-user30184).

Comment: Everything looks good to me. MBTiles cuts the image at the dateline because your tiff wraps around from West to East `Upper Left  ( (207d24' 5.35"W, 74d10'15.60"N))` . The MBTiles specification https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md does not support longitude 209 W which means the same as -209 E `For example, the bounds of the full Earth, minus the poles, would be: -180.0,-85,180,85`. In MBTiles Eastmost Siberia will appear far in the East, not to the West of Alaska. The whole map is still there even it is split into two halves.

Comment: it means the generated MBTiles dose not have any issue?

Comment: It shows both the Alaskan and Siberian sides OK on top of OpenStreetMap so I would say there is no issue with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer.